# PSProvider development: Get-ChildItem calls GetItem

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-provider

I have a class that extends `ContainerCmdletProvider`, in which I've overridden the following methods: `NewDrive`, `IsValidPath`, `ItemExists`, `HasChildItems`, `GetItem` and `GetChildItems`.

I can create a new drive (`New-PSDrive -Name test ...`), and successfully the child items from the root (`Get-ChildItem test:`). But when I try it on a sub-path that I know exists and has children (`Get-ChildItem test:path`) I get the same result as if I had run `Get-Item test:path`.

Using a debugger and setting breakpoints I can see which methods are called.
For `Get-ChildItem test:` it's, `ItemExists`, `GetChildItems`.
For `Get-ChildItem test:path` it's, `ItemExists`, `GetItem`.

Is this the expected behaviour? If so, how can I know the user's intention (viewing the item or its children)?
I'm surprised `HasChildItems` isn't called.

To output the `test:path` item, from both `GetChildItems` and `GetItem`, I use `WriteItemObject(item, itemPath, true)` passing the `isContainer` flag as `true`.

I've been following the [How to Create a Windows PowerShell Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/prog-guide/how-to-create-a-windows-powershell-provider?view=powershell-7.3) guide from Microsoft. I'm targeting PowerShell Core (I'm on version 7.3.7), but this is the only guide I've found.

Comment: Do you need the backslash?  Get-Item test:\path.  When you leave the backslash off in windows it will take the current selected directory.  So if you have test:\root\folder1\path.  If current folder is root you will not find the subfolder path.

Comment: I've played around with different combinations of slashes (`test:\path`, `test:path\`, `test:\path\`) but they all result in the same behaviour. Regardless, I'd never expect `GetItem` to be called when executing `Get-ChildItem`...

Comment: You may not have permission to read folder.  Try starting PS by right click shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: @jdweng That didn't make any difference, but I appreciate the help

Comment: @jdweng: There is nothing in this question that even remotely suggests that a permissions problem is involved.
Given the security risks involved, running code with elevation (as administrator) should always be a deliberate act that should be limited to operations that actually require elevated privileges. Casually suggesting it as a cure-all, which you seem to be in the habit of doing, does more harm than good.

Comment: @jdweng: As many times before, your comment is unrelated to the point that I was making. Temper tantrums with triple exclamation points do not change that fact. As usual: Please make sure you fully understand the question and have sufficient subject-matter expertise before commenting.

Comment: @mklement0 That worked. I had not read further and didn't realize that Container Providers only supported root containers with child items. I've now implemented a Navigation Provider and Get-ChildItem works (pretty much) as I expected. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your feedback, implementing a *navigation* provider rather than a *container* provider solved your problem, based on the following distinction:

[Implementing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/prog-guide/how-to-create-a-windows-powershell-provider?view=powershell-7.3) PowerShell [providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Providers) that support *hierarchies* comes in two flavors:

- [*Container* providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/prog-guide/creating-a-windows-powershell-container-provider):

  - *Container* providers only support a *two-level* hierarchy: containers at the root level whose children must be *non-container* items.
- [*Navigation* providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/prog-guide/creating-a-windows-powershell-navigation-provider):

  - *Navigation* providers support *arbitrarily deep* hierarchies, where every level may have a mix of container and non-container children.
    (An example of such a provider is the [*file-system* provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_FileSystem_Provider), whose *container* items are *directories*, and whose *non-container* items are *files*).